# Unmerge, Sort and Merged cells in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with the excel-vba, I have to sort the rows in ascending order  with merged cells, I know that the merged cell cannot be sorted that is why, this work around is the only solution to my problem. I need to unmerged the cells then copy the value of the first cell and paste it to the second cell, after that, the code will sort the list using the A column and C column. and then after that if the A and C column has an equal value, it will turn to merged cell.

I hope someone could help me with this project.

Also view this image to see the list.

[Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuH5v.png)

So, I constructed a code that will do this process but it cant.

```
    Sub Sort()
    On Error GoTo myErr
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim lstrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cel As Range

    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:C7")
    lstrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With myRange

    .UnMerge
    For Each cel In myRange
            If IsEmpty(cel) Then
                For i = 2 To lstrow
                   ' cel(i).Value = 1
                   Sheet1.Range(i).Copy Sheet1.Range(cel).PasteSpecial
                   Sheet1.Range("C3").CurrentRegion.Sort _
                   key1:=Sheet1.Range("C3"), order1:=xlAscending, _
                   Header:=xlGuess

                        Next i
             End If

            Next cel




    End With

    myErr:
    MsgBox "Unble to sort!"
    End Sub
```

> “No one is useless in this world who lightens the burdens of another. -Charles Dickens”

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to find `lstRow` before unmerging, use Column B — if the last row in Column A is merged, then the bottommost cell is empty! Or if you prefer, you can find `lstRow` after unmerging everything.

By looping through `myRange` you can both `UnMerge` any merged cells and populate the newly unmerged cells using the `MergeArea.address` of the original merged cell. After sorting on columns A and C, you can then loop through those columns, comparing each row to the row beneath. Only re-merge when both the row beneath is the same as the row above for both columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sort()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim address As String
Dim contents As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo myErr

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:C7")

' Get lstrow from Column B, if Column A has merged cells
lstrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

' Unmerge and populate
For Each rng In myRange
    If rng.MergeCells Then
        ' Get value from top left cell
        contents = rng.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value
        address = rng.MergeArea.address
        rng.UnMerge
        ws.Range(address).Value = contents
    End If
Next rng

' Sort
myRange.Sort key1:=ws.Range("A1:A" & lstrow), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, key2:=ws.Range("C1:C" & lstrow), _
    order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

' Turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Re-merge
With ws
    For l = 2 To lstrow
        If .Cells(l, 1).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 1).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 3).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 3).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value Then

            ' Merge column A
            Range(.Cells(l, 1).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 1)).Merge

            ' Merge column C
            Range(.Cells(l, 3).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 3)).Merge
        End If
    Next l
 End With

' Turn on alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

myErr:
    MsgBox "Unable to sort!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir? @Bigben?? How to fasten the sorting if the row is more than 300? also the merged cell is greater than to 2?

Comment: "The merged cell is greater than to 2" - meaning more than 2 rows are merged together? "Fasten the sorting if the row is more than 300" - meaning speed up?

Comment: I already did it sir, but the sorting of Rows takes 30 seconds. how to fasten it up?

Comment: To start, add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and set it back to `True` at the end.